# Psexec can't execute remote batch file

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am using `PSEXEC` to get registry key value. The below is my code.

PowerShell:

```
Set-Alias psexec "e:\test\psexec.exe"

psexec \\172.20.118.74 -i -d -s -u xsumrouadm -p Welkom01 /c "E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat"
```

Batch file:

```
@echo off &setlocal
reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\0011 /v "IEEE11nmode"
@echo >> \\esessmw2395\c$\test\QueryDeviceHealth-Registry.csv
```

I am getting error as below:

```
psexec :  At line:3 char:1
+ psexec \\in00121324 e:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The system cannot find the path specified.

Connecting to in00121324...
Starting PSEXESVC service on in00121324...
Connecting with PsExec service on in00121324...
Starting e:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat on in00121324...
PsExec could not start e:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat on in00121324:
```

Computer name modified to IPaddress

```
psexec :  At line:3 char:1
psexec \\172.20.118.74 -i -d -s -u xsumrouadm -p Welkom01 /c "E:\test\DeviceHeal ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
PsExec v2.11 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

The file exists.

Connecting to 172.20.118.74...
Starting PSEXESVC service on 172.20.118.74...
Connecting with PsExec service on 172.20.118.74...
Copying E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat to 172.20.118.74...
Error copying E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat to remote system:
```

Comment: The error says: `The system cannot find the path specified`. Looks like you need to double-check file names and paths. Read Sysinterals' forum for some [syntax tips](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-c-never-works_topic14792.html) too.

Comment: I am looking for the solution to the error: PsExec could not start e:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat on in00121324 and the error: Error copying E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat to remote system:

Comment: How about `/c` -> `-c`?

Comment: According to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psexec.aspx you should use `-c` if your intention is to copy the file to the remote machine before executing it. If the `.bat` file already exists on that machine and can be located by the PATH, you can skip the `-c` flag.

Comment: @PetSerAl `PsExec` accepts both notations.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different errors from two different commands there:

- `The system cannot find the path specified.`
  This error occurred, because you ran `PsExec` like this:

  ```
  psexec \\in00121324 e:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat
  ```

  Without the option `-c` the *local* file `E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat` is not copied to the remote host, and there was no *remote* file `E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat` available for execution.
- `The file exists.`
  This error occurred when you ran `PsExec` with the options `-c` *and* `-d` (the command accepts both `/` and `-` notation for parameters):

  ```
  psexec \\172.20.118.74 -i -d -s -u xsumrouadm -p Welkom01 /c "E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat"
  ```

  When you instruct `PsExec` to immediately detach from the remote process (`-d`) the file copied to the remote host is not removed after execution, so you probably have an artifact from a previous attempt in `C:\Windows` on the remote host. Remove that file (and the option `-d`) and the command should run as expected.

  ```
  psexec \\172.20.118.74 -i -s -u xsumrouadm -p Welkom01 -c "E:\test\DeviceHealthRegistry.bat"
  ```

  If you know that the file is already present on the remote host, you could also omit copying it again and run the command like this:

  ```
  psexec \\172.20.118.74 -i -d -s -u xsumrouadm -p Welkom01 DeviceHealthRegistry.bat
  ```